# Moving Box trait?

Tags: rust, memory-management

I am starting out with Rust -- day three of coding (coming from C++, Java, etc.)

I wish to use the following to build an Inventory system:

```
struct MeleeWeapon {...}
struct RangedWeapon {...}
struct Food {...}
struct Armour {...} // etc.

trait Item {...}
trait Weapon {...} // etc.

// these traits are implemented as necessary for the above structs, noting that all of them implement trait Item.
```

Now that I have the items laid out, I wish to create an inventory and allow items to be added to it. I know that Boxes are similar to C++ smart pointers and wish to move the Item from its original owner to the *items* ArrayVec.

```
struct Inventory {
    items: ArrayVec<Box<dyn Item>, 128>
}

impl Inventory {
    fn add<'a>(&self, item:  Box< &'a dyn Item>) -> bool {
        if self.items.is_full() {
            return false;
        }
        self.items.push(&item); // error

        return true;
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `Box<(dyn Item + 'static)>`
found reference `&Box<&'a (dyn Item + 'a)>`
```

Alas, I feel like I am missing something fundamental regarding how Rust manages pointers, but I don't know enough about rust to search for the correct solution. If someone has already answered this question -- which I am certain they probably have -- I wouldn't know the words to google for it...

Comment: The type in the struct is different from the type in the function argument. You should probably change the argument to `item: Box<dyn Item>`.

Comment: Please post a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in future that people can just copy-paste and it reproduces your problem exactly. Further, please don't paste errors from your IDE, but instead paste the output from `cargo check` here. It shows a lot more detail about your error and includes line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is as following:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

trait Item {}

struct Inventory {
    items: ArrayVec<Box<dyn Item>, 128>,
}

impl Inventory {
    fn add<'a>(&self, item: Box<&'a dyn Item>) -> bool {
        if self.items.is_full() {
            return false;
        }
        self.items.push(&item); // error

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:14:25
    |
14  |         self.items.push(&item); // error
    |                    ---- ^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found reference
    |                    |
    |                    arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `Box<(dyn Item + 'static)>`
            found reference `&Box<&'a (dyn Item + 'a)>`
note: associated function defined here
   --> /home/martin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/arrayvec-0.7.2/src/arrayvec.rs:175:12
    |
175 |     pub fn push(&mut self, element: T) {
    |            ^^^^
```

You have three independent problems in your code.

For one, pushing an item into a vector requires you to hand over ownership to the vector. You prevent this by passing a reference in. Do `self.items.push(item)` instead of `self.items.push(&item)`.

The second problem is that you accept `Box<&'a dyn Item>` as a parameter. A `Box` containing a `&` reference almost never makes sense, and also doesn't match the type you store in your `items` vector. Use `Box<dyn Item>` as a parameter type instead.

The third problem is that you can't actually modify the `items` variable, because your function takes `&self`, which means `self` is immutable. Use `&mut self` instead.

Here is the corrected code:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

trait Item {}

struct Inventory {
    items: ArrayVec<Box<dyn Item>, 128>,
}

impl Inventory {
    fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn Item>) -> bool {
        if self.items.is_full() {
            return false;
        }
        self.items.push(item);

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

As a further note, although arguably personal preference:

[`ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/latest/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html) offers a [`try_push`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/latest/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html#method.try_push) method which kind of already does what you are trying to implement.

So you can reduce your code down to:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

trait Item {}

struct Inventory {
    items: ArrayVec<Box<dyn Item>, 128>,
}

impl Inventory {
    fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn Item>) -> bool {
        self.items.try_push(item).is_ok()
    }
}
```

As another remark: Note that passing the `Box` into the `ArrayVec` transfers ownership of it into the `ArrayVec`. If the `try_push` fails, the object will be destroyed. That's why `try_push` returns a `CapacityError` on failure that hands the object you pushed back to you for further processing.

---

Yet another remark: I have the suspicion that you use `Box<&dyn Item>` because you want to keep the original object somewhere else.

You can't implement this situation with `Box`; you will have to use a reference counter like `Rc` or `Arc` (depends on whether or not you need thread safety). Note that this, however, will render the item immutable and you will have to read about the concept of interior mutability.

So long story short, if you want to keep the original object, you probably want to use `Rc<RefCell<dyn Item>>` or `Arc<Mutex<dyn Item>>` as the item type of your `ArrayVec` instead, depending on thread safety requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`push` expects an owned type, but you provided a reference.

That's what the error "Expeced `Box` found reference `&Box`" is talking about.

However, I do not recommend storing Boxed Trait Object for an inventory like structure. Since you **cannot get the concrete object back from a trait object**. Plus Box is heap allocated and requires dynamic dispatch at runtime, so have relative bad performance.

Use `enum` instead, they are intended for these use case.

```rust
struct MeleeWeapon1 {...}
struct MeleeWeapon2 {...}
struct RangedWeapon1 {...}
struct RangedWeapon2 {...}
struct Helmet1 {...}
struct Food1 {...}

trait RangedWeaponTrait {...}
trait MeleeWeaponTrait {...}
trait ArmorTrait {...}
trait FoodTrait {...}

enum MeleeWeapon {
    MeleeWeapon1(MeleeWeapon1),
    MeleeWeapon2(MeleeWeapon2),
}
enum RangedWeapon {
    RangedWeapon1(RangedWeapon1),
    RangedWeapon2(RangedWeapon2),
}
enum Weapon {
    Melee(MeleeWeapon),
    Ranged(RangedWeapon),
}

enum Helmet {
    Helmet1(Helmet1),
}
/* Other armor types */
enum Armor {
    Helmet(Helmet),
    /* Other armor types */
}

enum Food {
    Food1(Food1),
}

enum Item {
    Weapon(Weapon),
    Armor(Armor),
    Food(Food),
}

struct Inventory {
    items: ArrayVec<Item, 128>,
}
impl Inventory {
    pub fn add(&mut self, item: Item) -> Result<(), Item> {
        if self.items.is_full() {
            Err(item)
        } else {
            self.items.push(item);
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. I suppose the only downside of using enums is the lack of control for item state. For example, if your helmet becomes damaged or gun runs out of ammo, it would be difficult to record the fact thereof.

Comment: Unless rust allows an easy way

Comment: For example, if I picked up a bottle full of water and then another bottle, this time it is half-full, how would I record the state? At least in other languages, enums are archetypal and will only indicate that you have "a bottle of water" with no way of specifying "which bottle has more water".

Comment: @John Rust Enums are rich, which means you can store pretty much anything in Enum Variants, you can have a `WaterBottle` Type and store it in the enum, see [The Rust Book on Enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html)